# Google Drive and Google APIs Explorer - changing Image metadata - location

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I would like to update image location tags for files in Drive. At this point I have identified two methods that appear to be possibly able to do this and have attempted a change using the "Try this API" bar

- Files:update
  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update
- or Files:patch ...drive/v2/reference/files/patch

I supply a fileID, set the fields to "imageMediaMetadata/location" to filter the response to just the data I am interested in and set the request body as follows

```
{
  "imageMediaMetadata": {
    "location": {
      "latitude": -30.12345678901234
      "longitude": 170.12345678901234
    }
  }
}
```

Both methods return a green success code 200
and the return string, however the return string is showing the data unchanged (I am trying to change the latitude sign for this image).

```
 {
  "imageMediaMetadata": {
    "location": {
      "latitude": 30.12345678901234
      "longitude": 170.12345678901234
    }
  }
}
```

Another location for trying the update method is developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.update

This claims that it "Updates a file's metadata and/or content with patch semantics.".

Using the same inputs, this method returns an error code - 403, specifics below:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "fieldNotWritable",
    "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
 }
}
```

So it appears that either (a) there is something wrong with how I am forming the request, or (b) the location data is read only and can't be modified via the API.(Or perhaps this would work in normal use but not via the API explorer?)

Can anyone provide some more info? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."

Means that you cant change those fields VIA the API.  The field is read only.

If you check the documentation for [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) you will notice that some fields are writeable while others are not are blank.

*That being said I have send off an email to Google suggesting that they add read only instead of just leaving the fields blank for clarification.*

**Solution**: I suggest you try downloading the file and altering the location locally on your machine.

Comment: There is now an internal issue logged at Google which will address adding read only to the fields in question. This should help with clarity in the future.

Answer (score 1):

On the page you linked to (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) under section 'Request body' you can find a list of all writeable properties. The location is not there, so it is not writeable via this API.

However, I admit the response 200 is quite misleading in this case.

On [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) you find **all properties of the file resource**, with information, which of them are writeable.

Comment: And this answer differs from mine how?  You should simply have edited my answer and added the links.